# find cells with specific value and replace its value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Using pandas I have created a csv file containing 2 columns and saved my data into these columns. something like this:

```
fist                                      second
{'value': 2}                              {'name': 'f'}
{'value': 2}                              {'name': 'h'}
{"value": {"data": {"n": 2, "m":"f"}}}    {'name': 'h'}
...
```

Is there any way to **look for all the rows** whose the first column contains "data" and if any, only keep its value in this cell? I mean is it possible to change my third row from:

```
{"value": {"data": {"n": 2, "m":"f"}}}    {'name': 'h'}
```

to something like this:

```
{"data": {"n": 2, "m":"f"}}    {'name': 'h'}
```

and delete or replace the value of all other cells that does not contain `data` to something like `-`?
So my csv file will look like this:

```
fist                                      second
-                                         {'name': 'f'}
-                                         {'name': 'h'}
{"data": {"n": 2, "m":"f"}}               {'name': 'h'}
...
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

result = []
for line in open('file.json', 'r'):
    result.append(json.loads(line))

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)

df.to_csv('document.csv')

f = pd.read_csv("document.csv")
keep_col = ['first', 'second']
new_f = f[keep_col]
new_f.to_csv("newFile.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my short example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first' : [{'value': 2}, {'value': 2}, {"value": {"data": {"n": 2, "m":"f"}}}]
    ,'secound' : [{'name': 'f'}, {'name': 'h'},{'name': 'h'}]
})

a = pd.DataFrame(df["first"].tolist())
a[~a["value"].str.contains("data",regex=False).fillna(False)] = "-"
df["first"] = a.value
```

- first step is to remove the 'value' field. after this the value field
- if the new field contains the word "data" the field is set to true; all other fields are False, Numberic Fields have the value NaN this is Replaced with False. And the whole gets negated and replaced with "-"
- last step is to overwrite the column in the original Data Frame.

Comment: How about the case in which the data in a cell has several parts that I want to remove? I mean suppose I have `{"value": {"data": {"n": 2, "m": "f"}, "partt": {"f1": "c"}}}` How can I only keep the `{"data": {"n": 2, "m":"f"}}` part?

Comment: you could use `df["first"]=df["first"].apply(lambda x: {"data": x["value"]["data"]} if type(x["value"]) == type(dict()) else "-")` insted does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```
first=[{'value': 2} , {'value': 2} , {"value": {"data": {"n": 2, "m":"f"}}}, {"data": {"n": 2, "m":"f"}}]
second=[{'name': 'f'}, {'name': 'h'}, {'name': 'h'}, {'name': 'h'}]

df = pd.DataFrame({'first': first,
                   'second': second})

f = lambda x: x.get('value', x) if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan
df['first'] = df['first'].apply(f)
df['first'][~df["first"].str.contains("data",regex=False).fillna(False)] = "-"
print(df)
```

```
                          first         second
0  -                             {'name': 'f'}
1  -                             {'name': 'h'}
2  {'data': {'n': 2, 'm': 'f'}}  {'name': 'h'}
3  {'data': {'n': 2, 'm': 'f'}}  {'name': 'h'}
```